# git - fetch revision of branch without checking it out

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, versioning

Currently I'm generating build versions by using

```
git rev-list --count --first-parent $BRANCH_NAME
```

generally using both master and dev branch revisions eg `2.27`. When using a cicd pipeline (gitlab) I would have to checkout my project all over again which is seemingly overkill.

Is there a simple way to get the revision number of a branch without having to check it out first?

---

** **EDIT** **

---

I'm finding out that my ci pipeline does a partial check out my repo as the first step. It then checks out the current branch in a detached head state.

```
$ eval "$CI_PRE_CLONE_SCRIPT"

...

$ git branch # if run manually via script
* (HEAD detached at xxxxxx)
```

This is promising because it means I have more access to finding out information about other branches on the repo

** **Temporary Solution** **

After running `npm build` I am executing a node script to do the dirty work:

```
...

execSync('git checkout -b __headless__'); // to get away from headless state, so we can come back in a sec @jkr
// const current = execSync('git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD').toString();
execSync('git fetch origin master');
execSync('git checkout master');
const master = execSync('git rev-list --count --first-parent HEAD').toString().replace(/\s/, '');
execSync('git fetch origin dev');
execSync('git checkout dev');
const dev = execSync('git rev-list --count --first-parent HEAD').toString().replace(/\s/, '');
execSync(`git checkout __headless__`);

...
```

** **Temporary Solution Refactor** **

Here is what I ultimately ended up with

```
const check = execSync('git branch').toString();

if(check.indexOf('detached at') > -1) {
    execSync('git checkout -b __headless__'); // to get away from headless state, so we can come back in a sec @jkr
}

const current = execSync('git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD').toString();
execSync('git fetch origin master');
execSync('git checkout master');
const master = execSync('git rev-list --count --first-parent HEAD').toString().replace(/\s/, '');
execSync('git fetch origin dev');
execSync('git checkout dev');
const dev = execSync('git rev-list --count --first-parent HEAD').toString().replace(/\s/, '');
execSync(`git checkout ${current}`);

...
```

At some point I piece together the `master` and `dev` numbers and inject that as the build's version.

Comment: How do you track version are you using tags? This `git rev-list ...` looks strange in this context.

Comment: CI systems in general are difficult and annoying. But, as Marek R said, a simple `git rev-parse <expression>` is usually the way to solve the particular problem you are asking about. Whether your CI system can actually do this and use the result is a separate question. :-)

Answer (score 1):

My project is using tags to track version.
So to see from which version branch comes I do:

```sh
git describe --tags "--abbrev=0" "--match=v*.*.*" branchName
```

What does what I need.

If version information is kept in a tracked file you can view it this way:

```sh
git show branchName:current_version.txt
```

I see you used "version" and "revision" and if by that you mean sha-1 of commit then this is what you need:

```sh
git rev-parse branchName
```